# Is every field between $F$ and $F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$ of the form $F(\alpha_j,\cdots,\alpha_k)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Say I have a field $F$, and an extension field $L = F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$. Is it true that every $K$ such that

$$
F \subset K \subset F
$$

(all field extensions), $K = F(\alpha_j,\cdots,\alpha_k)$?

That is, $K$ is $F$ adjoined with any number of whichever $\alpha$s.

It seems to be so to me, since $F(\alpha_1)$ is the smallest field containing both $F$ and $\alpha_1$. So there is no field between $F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{n-1})$ and $L$, no field between $F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{n-1})$ and that last field, etc.

I realize that the alphas could be left out in different orders, to create different fields between $F$ and $L$ not of the form $F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k)$. But I think that if we take all of the $F(\alpha_i)$ and build upwards to $L$ in all possible ways, we'll get ever field, because $L$ is the smallest field to contain $F$ and all the $\alpha_i$.

It seems this is true since if there is a field $J$ between $F$ and $L$ and

$$
\forall i,\cdots,j\ni \alpha_i,\cdots,\alpha_j\in\{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n\}\quad J\ne F(\alpha_i,\cdots,\alpha_j)\\
\implies\exists\beta\in J\ni\beta\not\in F(\alpha_i,\cdots\alpha_j)\text{ and }\beta\in L
$$

But I think that would mean that $L$ is not the smallest field containing $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$

Comment: $$\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$$

Comment: The error in your thinking is exposed in the third paragraph. $F(\alpha_1)$ is, indeed, the smallest field containing $F$ and and $\alpha_1$, but in between there may be other fields that contain $F$ but do not contain $\alpha_1$.